# Providing a background service for other apps

Tags: android, service

I'm new to Android development and I couldn't find this in the Dev Guide.

I would like to create a background service so that any other app could connect to it and get some data from it. I saw android.app.Service, but it seems that it only allows other apps to ping the service, it doesn't allow them to register for some specific events.
I had in mind something like the built in LocationManager and its addProximityAlert or even requestLocationUpdates.

Is anything like this possible with the existing sdk?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this sample could help you: [RemoteService](http://developer.android.com/intl/it/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.html).

This is the description from android developer site:

> Remote Service Controller and Remove
>   Service Binding
>       Demonstrates starting a service in a separate process, by assigning
>   android:process=":remote" to the
>   service in the AndroidManifest.xml
>   file. Shows how those clients can
>   either start/stop it with {@link
>   android.content.Context#startService
>   Context.startService} and {@link
>   android.content.Context#stopService
>   Context.stopService}, or bind and call
>   it with {@link
>   android.content.Context#bindService
>   Context.bindService} and {@link
>   android.content.Context#unbindService
>   Context.unindService}. Binding is
>   similar to the local service sample,
>   but illustrates the additional work
>   (defining aidl interfaces) needed to
>   interact with a service in another
>   process. Also shows how a service can
>   publish multiple interfaces and
>   implement callbacks to its clients.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to android development. I hope you enjoy your stay :D.
About your question:

What you are asking is done with a [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Service.html).
If you want apps to register for events what is usually done is the following:

- Create the service with all the logic.
- Make the service send a Broadcast msg.
- All interested apps will have a receiver class to get that msg.

I would like to know what you are trying to do to give you further assistance.