# Not allowed to bind to service Intent

Tags: android, service

I write an android service of get weather, and the AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.weather"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <service
            android:name=".WeatherService"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now, I want let another apk to start this service:

```
Intent service = new Intent();
service.setClassName("com.my.weather", "com.my.weather.WeatherService");
context.bindService(service, weatherServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

And I got the error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14068): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.test/com.my.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { cmp=com.my.weather/.WeatherService }
```

How can I solved this issue?

Other apk is use the Messenger method to communication with weather service.

================================================================================

Thanks all!

Now I modify my weather service's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.weather"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <service
            android:name=".WeatherService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":remote" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.my.weather.WeatherService"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And I use this method to start:

```
Intent service = new Intent("com.my.weather.WeatherService");
context.bindService(service, weatherServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Then I got the warning message:

```
W/ActivityManager(131): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.my.weather.WeatherService }: not found
```

Comment: Looks fine. Have you tried cleaning your WeatherService project and reinstalling it?

Comment: Dear David, it's the same when I clean and rebuild and reinstall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880450/providing-a-background-service-for-other-apps/2881548#2881548) says from documentation:

> If we want to make this service run in a remote process (instead of
>   the standard one for its .apk), we can use `android:process` in its
>   manifest tag to specify one:
>
> ```
> <service android:name=".app.MessengerService"
>         android:process=":remote" />
> ```

Also note that the name `remote` chosen here is arbitrary, and you can use other names if you want additional processes. The `:` prefix appends the name to your package's standard process name. With that done, clients can now bind to the service and send messages to it. Note that this allows clients to register with it to receive messages back as well.

**Edit1**:
Second, if the service element (in manifest) contains an action string, use it. For example if your service declared like this:

```
<service android:name="com.sample.service.serviceClass"  
            android:exported="true" android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:process=":remote">
   <intent-filter><action android:name="com.sample.service.serviceClass"></action>
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

So do this in `onCreate()` method of your service:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
      Intent intent=new Intent("com.sample.service.serviceClass");  
      this.startService(intent);
}
```

I saw that in this question:
[Unable to start Service Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439356/unable-to-start-service-intent/3439838#3439838)

**Edit2**:
I saw your manifest again.It seems that your manifest has no `Main/Launcher Activity`.In `android 3.1 and later` it causes no service be available.*`In fact for`**`security`**`reason all services,receivers,... that you declare in manifest,will not register unless your App run explicitly by user`* and this needs to a Main/Launcher Activity.So you have to add such Activity to your App and be care that it has already been performed.

Comment: Change in onCreate of service to activity. Any how this didnt solve my problem at all.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. For me the problem was that I first installed the app using the API and then app that provided the API. Uninstalling/Reinstalling the first app solved the problem.

Update: To avoid the problem **both** apps should define the permission in their manifest.

Comment: what permission?

Comment: @user9599745 custom service permission which declared in <service .. android:permission="..." />

Answer (score 2):

Add an intent-filter with an action to your WeatherService:

```
<service
    android:name=".WeatherService"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="this.is.my.custom.ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Then, when you go to bind with bindService() in your other app, use this intent:

```
new Intent("this.is.my.custom.ACTION")
```

Comment: This should work, (and in this case, you don't need `android:exported="true"` because the default for `exported` is `true` if there are intent-filters present). However, there is no reason that the code posted won't work. It is possible to start a service using an explicit intent.

Comment: I got warning message: W/ActivityManager(131): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.my.weather.WeatherService }: not found

Comment: @David Wasser using exported attribute saved my life. Now I must address why Activity of Service is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

When you call bindService for a remote service, you should set your packageName too.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.my.weather.WeatherService");
intent.setPackage("com.my.weather");
bindService(intent, serConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by David Wasser in a comment so I thought I share.

In the Manifest you can set exported attribute to true. This makes the service accessible to other apps.

Manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".MyUsefulService_"
                android:exported="true"/>
```

MyActivity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("jav.android.app",jav.android.app.MyUsefulService_");

bindService(this,MyServiceConnection,0);
```

Answer (score -1):

In ur activity class do ... suppose BothButton is Activity class name and CleverTexting is Service class name, And u want to call  an activity from  a service and than service from activity . If ur code is working fine in more than 4.0 android version than u can do like this there will not be any problem.

```
CleverTexting mService ; 

public void setService(CleverTexting listener) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     mService = listener;
}
```

and in ur Service class do... where u want to call ur activity

```
BothButton mBothButton;

mBothButton = new BothButton(this);
    mBothButton.setService(this);
```

Comment: This only works if the service and activity is in the same process. Which is only possible if they are of the same app.