# java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent in one plus device

Tags: android, voice-recognition, bindservice

I wrote a speech recognition app using android's built-in speech recognition classes.

Once in a while the following `Exception` shows up in my developer console when the `startListening()` function is called on the speech recognizer object obtained using `createSpeechRecognizer(context)` function.
I am using Android one plus one device.
I have initialize voice recognition like this

```
mSpeechRecognizer = peechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getActivity());
mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 4000);
// mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 4000);
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);        

mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
                "en");
mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                getActivity().getPackageName());
mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);
mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
```

And Nothing happen after startlistening method.

Comment: Similar qsn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007139/not-allowed-to-bind-to-service-intent

Comment: post your code what you did

Comment: @Vijay Patle Is this the way to post (dump) code in the question? I understand for once when people post code without proper indentation, but this...